# how to export python large results to txt file

Tags: python, export

I have large data output from python that I can't just CtrlCthe entire output and CtrlV into txt files.

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    IOPub data rate exceeded.
    The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
    to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
    To change this limit, set the config variable
    `--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

    
    Current values:
    NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
    NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)

So, I want to save it directly using queries.
```

I've tried to import sys and write a txt file but failed.

Is there any way I can use to export and save this large txt output in python?
[image]

this is an image for better understanding of my data after adjusting `print(giRaw)`

Comment: Have you tried changing the config variable as mentioned in the snippet above?

Comment: @ddcastrodd, I thought about it, But was kinda scared that my notebook might shut down everything since it's old and file is really big. it's around 500 of biology thesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as simple as the below:

```
with open(FILE_NAME, 'a') as the_file:
    the_file.write('<<your text here>>')
```

OR

```
with open(FILE_NAME, 'a') as the_file:
    print("hi there", file=the_file)
```

Comment: I'd like to export the entire <giRaw> file. sadly it didn't work. Could you look over the additional picture, please?

Comment: @hollyjolly, you want to export the variable, <giRaw> to a file, right? We can replace the same in the first code block via `the_file.write(f{your_variable>})`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're having the text in a variable in your program, you can use the following code snippet.

```py
# Assume your text is present in the variable "text"
text = 'blab blab ....'

# specify your file path
file_path = '/home/user/data.txt'

with open(file_path, 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(text)
```

Comment: Could you look over the additional picture, please? I'd like to export print(giRaw) result

Comment: @hollyjolly You can replace the variable, use `giRaw` instead of  `text`.